# Running standardized/unstandardized regression equation on SPSS

Tags: regression, self-study, spss, standardization

I am working on a regression assignment using SPSS.  I have raw, centered, and z scores for the data.  I already regressed the DV and IV and see the unstandardized and standardized coefficients under the coefficients output box.

My standardized regression equation is: Y’=1727.528X+-6290.967 
and unstandardized regression equation is: Y’=.633x

How do I write out standardized and unstandardized regression equation for each score?

Do I need to check the standardized and unstandardized boxes under the Linear Regression> Save..._menu for each IV?

Comment: I think your first equation is the unstd. regression....

Comment: Can you double check? Standardized regression shouldn't have intercept.